# SSAS Tabular using CSV files from SFTP

Tags: ssis, ssas, sftp, ssas-tabular

I wan to prepare a model in SSAS - Tabular using csv files placed in SFTP Folder.
Is there any way I can connect to these CSV files as a source to my SSAS - Tabular Model?
 If not, what are options I have to get the them to my model?

PS: I want to use them in PowerBI Report but cannot connect them directly due to size of the files.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can [load csv files into Tabular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/connect-to-a-flat-file-ssas?view=sql-server-2014), or if your compatibility mode supports it use the Power Query interface in SSDT.

The other option if you are using Azure Analysis Services is to use [Azure Data Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/analysisservices/using-azure-analysis-services-on-top-of-azure-data-lake-storage) to store your files

However, it would always be best to have a defined process to load them into a database first, for example using SSIS or Data factory then load them into SSAS or Power BI that way, using Direct Query if they are to big for the Power BI file and or data model size limits

Comment: thanks for your reply. I could not see the option to connect to SFTP from visual studio. The files are in SFTP and I cannot copy them to local drive due to security issues.